# Expedite data mining in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining

I am a complete novice in python and data mining but I'm working on a tight deadline and have been forced to come up with some jerry-rigged solutions for a project I'm on. It has proven to be extremely time-consuming and I'm thinking there must be a better way.

Right now, I have cobbled together a web scraper from some CLI tools that distribute a queue of assets to scrape into pieces. I then uploaded the code to a google colab and have it running on 3 computers in 8 instances, on 5 emails, each working on their own piece of the list of assets.

I have not yet implemented exponential backoff or jitter, and a "104 Error: Connection Terminated by Peer" seems to be the main obstacle in my way at this time.

Running this rube goldberg machine makes me feel like I'm shoveling coal in the bowels of a ship. Colab instances constantly crash and need to be restarted and I don't know how to save my work when the kernel disconnects, so I'm repeating a lot of work.

Can someone please tell me that there is a better way of doing this? One that does not demand near-constant attention and take hours to orchestrate? Would multiple workers run into the same rate limit errors? I've been told that Apache Spark (or PySpark more specifically) may be the solution to my problems. Where should I start to look for better options?

Any and all input would be greatly appreciated.